# ¿Cuales son las malas practicas del siguiente código en PHP y como lo refactorizarian?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, revisión-de-código

Este es mi código:

```
   public function post_confirm(){
    $id = Input::get('service_id');
    $servicio = Service::find($id);
    //dd($servicio);
    if($servicio != NULL){
    if($servicio->status_id == '6'){
        return Response::json(array('error' => '2'));
    }
    if($servicio->driver_id == NULL && $servicio->status_id == '1'){
        $servicio = Service::update($id, array(
                        'driver_id' => Input::get('driver_id'),
                        'status_id' => '2'
                            //Up Carro
                            //,'pwd' => ms5(Input::get('pwd')))
        ));
        Driver::update(Input::get('driver_id'), array(
            "available" => '0'
        ));
        $driverTmp = Driver::find(Input::get('driver_id'));
        Service::update($id, array(
                'car_id' => $driverTmp->car_id  
                    //Up Carro
                    //, 'pwd' => md5(Input::get('pwd'))
        ));
        //Notificar a usuario!!
        $pushMessage = 'Tu servicio ha sido confirmado!';
        /* $Servicio = Service::find($id);
           $push = Push::maker();
           if ($servicio->user->type == '1'){//iphone*/
           $pushAns = $push->ios($servicio->user->uuid, $pushMessage);
           } else{
           $pushAns = $push->android($servicio->user-uuid, $pushMessage);
           }) */
        $servicio = Service::find($id);
        $push = Push::maker();
        if($servicio->user->uuid == ''){
            return Response::json(array('error' => '0'));
        }
        if ($servicio->user-type == '1'){ //iPhone
            $result = $push->ios($servicio->user->uuid, $pushMessage, 1, 'honk.wav', 'Open , array('serviceId' => $servicio->id));
        } else{
            $result = $push->android2($servicio->user->uuid, $pushMessage, 1, 'default', 'Open , array('serviceId' => $servicio->id));
        }
        return Response::json(array('error' => '0'));
    } else {
        return Response::json(array('error' => '1'));
    }
    } else {
        return Response::json(array('error' => '3'));
    }

}
```

Comment: Deberías poner el código en vez de una imagen...

Comment: Puedes agregar el código como texto? Es mejor de esa manera.

Comment: Poner una imagen, es una mala practica =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voy a dar algunas sugerencias de las cuales puedes iniciar el refactoring completo, pues reescribir el método entero y explicar todo sería un poco extenso:

- Tal y como lo dijo Paris: [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/), es vital en Laravel y en prácticamente cualquier proyecto PHP, por ende esto aplica para todas tus clases y hasta helpers.
- Utilizar [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding) de Laravel nos ahorra tiempo, líneas de código y dolores de cabeza, es extremadamente útil.
- ¿Es un controlador lo que nos muestras? De ser así, no debería ser responsabilidad de él la lógica de la aplicación, considera mover la lógica a un servicio o a otra capa.
- A menos que utilices una versión muy antigua de php (no debería ser el caso si usas Laravel), puedes utilizar `[]` en vez de `array()`.
- Elimina comentarios que no tienen sentido o que son muy obvios, si necesitas tener ese código "por si lo necesito luego", bórralo, el control de versiones es tu amigo (Git).
- Comparar el valor `null` con == puede hacer menos legible el código, considera utilizar la función `is_null()`
- Hay muchos condicionales y muchos `return`, lo cual hace bastante complejo entender el código. Considera dividir el código y utilizar un solo `return` si es posible, manejando una variable o una propiedad del objeto.
- Utiliza traducciones en vez de escribir cadenas de texto directamente, nunca sabes si vas a necesitar idiomas adicionales y en caso que necesites la misma cadena en otra parte del código, evitarás redundancia.

Answer (score 1):

Veo que el código está relacionado con Laravel por lo que lo más recomendable es que uses PSR-2 para que concuerde con el estandar usado por Laravel.
Si usas algún IDE como Eclipse puedes configurarlo para que haga el formateo de forma automática de acuerdo al estandar que elijas.

Answer (score -1):

Sería una buena idea representar las variables constantes que permitan saber que significa cada valor.

Ejemplo:

```
$OFF_LINE = 6;

if ($servicio->status_id == $OFF_LINE) ...
```

en vez de

```
$servicio->status_id == '6'
```

Esto haría que el código sea mas legible.

Comment: aunque pongas la variable en mayúscula queda una variable...

Comment: En ese orden de ideas sería mejor una constante que una variable.